# Percent scale exceed 100% than color specified in aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this (this is a sample, my real data is very much larger)

```
structure(list(sample = structure(c(7L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("D", 
"B", "C", "E", "F", "A", "G"), class = "factor"), value = c(1.57560386370811, 
2.74767123459724, 1.48766063814693, 0.261551226670014, 1.00306151063661, 
1.02247863217139, 1.76353144287261, 2.23587290569418, 1.49168023330427, 
2.11621214818055, 1.27094679058081, 2.73839511842485, 1.87583038042473, 
1.59641420780167, 2.19836509026318, 0.635473395290403, 0.192993714489996, 
1.92481798200276, 1.58194775012715, 1.26479921517767, 0.327744730973777, 
1.11285902151151, 0.699530216689122, 1.59166071568725, 1.77676535187062, 
1.75986030495188, 1.31865020998268, 1.34421317790374, 1.03179959677329, 
1.43498038031802, 2.1072043118662, 1.14001243767691, 2.58744366379114, 
1.53324102734542, 1.34507268247757, 1.84174496717647, 1.90615474653985, 
1.7210096880912, 1.41695785259264, 0.124163802789654, 2.06258611055419, 
0.788038275478947, 1.32879855922399, 2.58393870879032, 2.26249595219018, 
2.05452405403729, 0.832090014427472, 1.4257137557524, 0.901623893164089, 
2.68079592002146, 1.05703668787781, 2.28339182829257, 0.890065229700846, 
1.63963247229921, 0.276160235737066, 1.38070909797962, 1.74373583704741, 
2.11923229219318, 1.77562483894366, 2.6259241843592, 1.34597293869339, 
1.97292044285211, 1.08219553003877, 2.09203186946828, 1.497866136777, 
0.331141762468312, 0.181744531972837, 2.22002119299133, 1.23579133952328, 
1.40361027815778, 1.16220617126205, 2.05121351532439, 0.885674235983964, 
0.373502647617544, 1.18266440387724, 1.77656044315736, 1.25666361193225, 
1.2378693071306, 2.01761459936079, 2.57802071105584, 1.65847348138692, 
1.63150167437282, 1.49009197829826, 0.120728043996333, 1.48892124132217, 
1.85182701968466, 1.87423503572575, 0.117067941873975, 0.442659100919283, 
1.19701680876233, 1.966186777295, 1.03264695689504, 1.8188161314621, 
1.70641589964924, 1.37212626434516, 1.90022561488552, 1.22146530281275, 
1.39344122533287, 1.9761657281558, 1.22903027342813)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I create plot without a color in `aes` it creates in expected way

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = value)) +
    geom_density() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]

If I add `sample` variable for defining color in aesthetics the Y axis exceeds limit in 100%

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = value, color = sample)) +
    geom_density() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

[image]

I have tried to group dataframe and use `sample` variable as factor but always get this unexpected behaviour. I am out of ideas how to fix it.

Comment: This is the wrong approach to take imo. Continuous probability density functions can take arbitrarily large values so any idea of percentage is suspect. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) for an extreme example

Comment: In general, all pdfs must integrate to 1 (since something must happen). If the range in which there is a positive probability is less than 1 unit large then there must be at least one value where its pdf is greater than 1. As far as I know, scale_y_continuous only converts stuff to percentage by multiplying it by 100 and putting a percent sign after it, so if the pdf of the distribution returns something like 1.2 then it will blindly convert it to 120%.

Comment: If you're confused by what I said, you might want to consider asking this question in the statistics stack exchange instead

Comment: @user3124634 Ok, I think I understand. Problem that I used not appropriate tool (plot type) for my needs and not fully understanding pdf. I will keep dig in to this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this is overkill, but the following code may help: `plot(density(rnorm(100, 0, 1)), xlim=c(-9, 9), ylim=c(0, .5), col="red"); lines(density(rnorm(100, 0, 1.5)), col="blue"); lines(density(rnorm(100, 0, 3)), col="green"); abline(h=0, lty=3)`. Data drawn from a normal distribution, equal in the number of values and the mean value, but differing in the standard error have different maximum densities on the y-axis, but all three have areas under their curve of 1.0.